# URL image not showing up in Android Studio when using Glide

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-glide

My activity is made up of 12 ImageViews. When the user clicks on one of the grid, I want to replace the default rectangular X image with an URL image. I have been trying to use Glide to set the image. However, I kept having issues with the alignment of the pictures.

**Before setting URL image using glide**

[image]

**After setting URL image using glide**

[image]

**This is my code in the corresponding layout page.**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gameScoreDynamic"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gameScoreDynamic"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/recx"></ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/recx"></ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/recx"></ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gameScoreDynamic"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/recx"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/recx"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/recx"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gameScoreDynamic"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/recx"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/recx"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/recx"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gameScoreDynamic"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/recx"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/recx"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/recx"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**This is my code in the activity page.**

```
public class GamePage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

....
....
....

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_page);

    ImageView img1 = findViewById(R.id.image1);
    img1.setOnClickListener(this);
    gridIDs.add(img1.getId());
    Glide.with(this)
            .load("https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/280h/tree-desert_JMTQNOJWU8.jpg")
            .into(img1);
}
```

I would like to replace the 12 rectangular boxes with X with URL images. Have tried to fiddle with the ImageView layout settings but to no avail. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `wrap_content` for the height and width of the *ImageViews*. When Glide loads the new image, the view expands to accommodate the size of the new image.

There is likely to be a way to specify different behavior with Glide, but another approach would be to set the size of the *ImageViews* programmatically to a fixed size based upon the intrinsic size of "drawable/recx". In the activity's `onCreate()`:

```
ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.image7);
Drawable d = iv.getDrawable();
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = iv.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
lp.height = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
```

You could also just set the size in the XML.

Your XML is a mixture of different layout attributes, so it looks like you have tried several things in XML. Another thought is to use `0dp` along with weights or other means to adjust the size of the *ImageViews* rather than use `wrap_content`. This may be a better way since it would not need any additional code. (It it works, that is. You will have to try it out.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your reply was very helpful and I managed to solve the problem after tinkering around the layout a bit more. What I had to do basically was to fix the ImageViews dimensions.  Thank you  and Happy New Year 2023!